# What package do i need to install for using routing sockets?

Tags: c, linux, networking, routes

i am trying code given in Unix Network Programming by Richard Stevens. but i am not able to get the code to compile.

here is the source code.
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15213-f00/unpv12e/libroute/

i don't have the header file net/if_dl.h and the net/route.h header file does not include the constants and structures that the code uses.

Comment: Have you grepped to see if the constants are in a different header file? It may be that it has just moved over the past 8 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a BSD-specific API, and linux doesn't support it.  The
equivalent functionality (not source-compatible) is provided by the
netlink socket family. "man 7 netlink" should get you started, but
you're likely going to need to do some porting work.

Answer (score 7):

Please note, you DO NOT need to make in that folder "libroute"

See the Document:

```
cd ../libroute # only if your system supports 4.4BSD style routing sockets
make           # only if your system supports 4.4BSD style routing sockets

cd ../libxti   # only if your system supports XTI
make           # only if your system supports XTI
```

Linux is not BSD style routing, just go to ../intro and build examples~!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not on a machine where I can do this right now, but perhaps I can still help. If your distribution uses `yum` (e.g. RHEL):

```
yum provides if_dl.h
```

Or if you use `apt` (e.g. Ubuntu/Debian):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search if_dl.h
```

If `apt-file` is already installed, the first step won't be necessary, and I can't remember for sure if the second is. Also, I believe both package managers work both with filename and with full path.

Hopefully this will work for you or someone else reading this, and you'll get your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/freebsd-glue_0.2.20_amd64.deb.html
just install freebsd-glue deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install freebsd-glue
```

Answer (score 0):

try to copy a if_dl.h from net , and put it in /usr/include/net .
may be it works and maybe it needs other libs. 
Maybe my English is not so good . Forgive me.

Comment: You should first reproduce the problem in your environment and provide a concrete solution, instead of "try/maybe" answers. StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. It is a question/answer site, so your answer should be fully checked before posting.